# How to query autocomplete for restaurants in Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I am looking for an example query that returns a list of just restaurants for use as an autocomplete given a piece of partial text with or without a coordinates position.

I see an example with geocode, but this returns physical places.

I tried using type=establishment  but I get a number of results that are not restaurants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. you can always check the documentation of google places api for such questions. The supported types are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

```
    <label for="restaurant">
         <input id="restaurant" name="restaurant">
    </label>
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById('restaurant');
        var options = {
            types: ['(restaurant)']
        };
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input,options);
    </script>
```

Comment: How can I do this from curl or from a web server?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd be interested in this feature request: [Issue 3538: Allow Places types in autocomplete](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3538).